# Linkedin OAuth is not working

Tags: javascript

I am new for Ionic. i am developing linkedin Signin for my App. for linkedin Oauth 2 i used cordovaoauth .it goes to linkedin signin page But It gives the error like - Client missing or specified more than once.

my code:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.linkedinLogin = function () {
            $cordovaOauth.linkedin('ClientId', 'clientSecret', ['https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=ClientId&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=9898989898', 'r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'], '9898989898').then(function (result) {
                console.log("Response Object -> " + JSON.stringify(result));
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("Error -> " + error);
                alert(error);
            });
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

You're getting errors because you're including an invalid scope:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=ClientId&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=9898989898
```

Remove that from the array and try again.

Best,